# Can someone explain what String temp does in this program?

Tags: java

What does `String temp` do in this program? I'm new to coding, and I understand everything else, but I can't really wrap my head around the process when `String temp` is used.

```
public class DeckOfCard2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] SUITS = {
            "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"
        };

        String[] RANKS = {
            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
        };

        // initialize deck
        int n = SUITS.length * RANKS.length;
        String[] deck = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < RANKS.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SUITS.length; j++) {
                deck[SUITS.length*i + j] = RANKS[i] + " of " + SUITS[j];
            }
        }

        // shuffle
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i));
            String temp = deck[r];
            deck[r] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = temp;
        }

        // print shuffled deck
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(deck[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `temp` allows `deck[i]` and `deck[r]` to swap: the swapping cannot be done without an extra variable since when `deck[r] = deck[i];` is done, the value of `deck[r]` is lost

Comment: `temp` is used as temporaly storage for something.

Answer (score 1):

In order to swap two values, usual practice is to save one to a temporary value. Otherwise, you would overwrite one of them before that value has been reassigned.

But it is possible to swap two values without saving one using the **XOR** operator. In the following case, I am using `ints` to demonstrate.

```
int a = 47;
int b = 99;
System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d%n", a, b);

a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;

System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d%n", a, b);
```

prints

```
a = 47, b = 99
a = 99, b = 47
```

The above method doesn't lend (or easily lend) itself to objects. It is much more efficient to just swap references using a temporary value.